# How can I capture the event filtering a datatable in primefaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

How can I capture the event filtering a `p:dataTable` in PrimeFaces. I need to calculate some values ​​associated with the results list when filtered and I have to do the calculations using the filtering table:

```xml
<p:dataTable  id="tabla_gral" rendered="#{consumoMaterial.verTabla}" var="item"
              paginator="true" rows="15" rowKey="#{item.no}"
              value="#{consumoMaterial.listadoConsumo}"
              filteredValue="#{consumoMaterial.listadoConsumoFiltered}">
```

But I want to do the calculation every time you use the filtrate.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Primefaces `p:dataTable` has AJAX event `filter` which you can define on `p:dataTable`:

```xml
<p:dataTable>
  <p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{myBean.filterListener}"/>
</p:dataTable>
```

Now in your backing bean define method `filterListener`:

```java
public void filterListener(FilterEvent filterEvent) {
  // your code here...
}
```

Now, your `filterListener` function will be called on every filter event.

Comment: hey, my country dont have access to download http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf

Comment: hey, my country dont have access to download http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf, can you help me to get this...???

Comment: Try [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mikujzmmduw9ian/primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf) or [here](http://www.filedropper.com/primefacesusersguide35)

Comment: I want to call filterListener after filter is complete, event="filter" call filterlistener before filteredValue is filling

Comment: I had to remove parameter to make it work in PF6.1 like this: `public void filterListener() {..}`

Comment: Where is the ajax event "filter" documented? I got a look into the Primefaces Users Guide (http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) but couldn't find anything about this.