# Do something after widgetVar.filter() is really completed and has updated p:datatable

Tags: ajax, primefaces, datatable, filtering

I have a datatable (primefaces 4.0), and I'm using widgetVar to apply re-filter table after update of data.
I need to call function `doSomething()` ONLY when `employeesDataTable_WV.filter();` has really finished to filter table and update it.

in this link is show how work `filter` function

https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/2686053/

it seems to do an ajax request and than update the component.

Here my example code

```
<h:form id="form">

    <p:remoteCommand name="myRemote" actionListener="viewEmployeesManagedBean.refreshEmployees"
            update=":form:employeesDataTable" 
            oncomplete="employeesDataTable_WV.filter();doSomething();"/>

    <p:dataTable id="employeesDataTable"
        value="#{viewEmployeesManagedBean.employees}" var="employee" widgetVar="employeesDataTable_WV">
        [...]
    </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

I need to call doSomething function ONLY after datatable is filtered and updated by employeesDataTable_WV.filter() function.
All my tests did not work and the `doSomething` function is always invoked before the update of the datatable.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is to add a ajax event handler to the `p:dataTable` and put the `doSomething()` in the `oncomplete` of the filter event and remove it from the `p:remoteCommand`.

```
<p:ajax event="filter" oncomplete="doSomething()" />
```

If you do not want/need to have a roundTrip to the server, you can replace the `p:ajax` with the PrimeFaces Extensions [`pe:javascript`](http://primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/clientBehaviours/javascriptBehaviour.jsf)

And if you only want it to happen when the `filter()` is called directly on the widgetVar, just set a semaphore directly before calling the `filter()` and check in the `doSomething()` if it was set.

```
    <p:remoteCommand ...
        oncomplete="mySemaphore = true;employeesDataTable_WV.filter();"/>

function doSomething() {
    if(mySemaphore == true;) {

      ...

      mySemaphore = false;
    }

    // just do nothing if called from editing in one of the filter fields
}
```

This should work for 4.0 but also for later versions up to the current (at time of answering) 6.1-SNAPSHOT (and most likely beyond)

**See also**

- [How can I capture the event filtering a datatable in primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903264/how-can-i-capture-the-event-filtering-a-datatable-in-primefaces)

Comment: sorry but in this way is catched also the moment in which user type something on filter of column

`<p:column filterBy="#{employee.employeeName}" headerText="employeeId" footerText="contains" filterMatchMode="contains">
   <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Employee Name"></h:outputText>
   </f:facet>
   <h:outputText value="#{employee.employeeName}"></h:outputText>
  </p:column>`


it is true or am I wrong?
I don't want this kind of behaviour

Comment: Correct, is that what you meant by ONLY?Then be creative (as a developer) in the oncomplete of the remote command before the `employeesDataTable_WV.filter();` set a 'semaphore' and in the `doSomething()` first check if it is set. If not just directly return from it, otherwise actually do something .